# Cannot get status of "Adaptec AAC-RAID (Rocket) (rev 02)" HW RAID card

Tags: raid

```
SERVER:~ # lspci | grep -i raid
0000:04:00.0 RAID bus controller: Adaptec AAC-RAID (Rocket) (rev 02)
SERVER:~ # arcconf getconfig 1 pd
```

and after the arcconf, the command just hangs.. the server seems OK. But the stucked arcconf struggles me, could there be a problem? How can I get the status of the mentioned RAID card, if the status command just timeouts? .. waited 10 minutes for it..

Comment: is there any dump / error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server poweroff / on resolved the problem..